# Checking for NULL in php

Tags: php, null

I am trying to check for a string for being empty or NULL:

```
if (strlen((string)$comment) > 0 And !($comment === NULL))
{   ....   }
```

but it does not seem to picking up the NULL.

Comment: What does your variable contain? Use `var_dump()` to probe the failing cases.

Comment: var_dump says it is null but I can't get anything to agree. Using if (is_null($comment)) { stuff } it doesn't do the stuff.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) instead of checking the string length and if it is null.

```
if (!empty($comment))
```

For the sake of learning, you can use [`is_null()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) in your specific example:

```
if (strlen((string)$comment) > 0 && !is_null($comment))
```

But my first example is the better way to do it.

Comment: `empty` also triggers for the string `"0"` though.

Comment: @mario True. The answer to your comment will be telling.

Answer (score 2):

use this as your conditional:

```
if (!is_null($comment) && strlen($comment) > 0)
{   ....   }
```

but as John Conde suggested, you could shorten this to a single check by using [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) but know that this will check if the value in `$comment` is `''`, `NULL`, `'0'`, `false`, and `0`

```
if (!empty($comment))
{   ....   }
```

Comment: The `> 0` condition may be redundant even. And I'd avoid the explicit casting as well. If OP passed an array, he'd rather want a warning than an incorrect result (strlen((string)array()) == 5).

Comment: what if `$comment` represents an integer that he wants converted to a string to test the length, though the `>0` may be redundant it could be easier to follow for him as he looks over the code later on.

Comment: `strlen` does an implicit string cast, except for NULL, arrays and objects IIRC. But true, the `>0` can be kept if it's for readability.

Comment: I learned something new, thanks Mario! I'm editing my answer to remove the explicit casting.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use: `if (!is_null($comment) )
{   ....   }`